# Prevent change number to local in android app code

Tags: android, localization, android-drawable, android-resources, android-assets

In my android app , when try get resource in asset folder by name that contain number throw exception

```
     int i=9;
     int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("level_1_img_" + i, "id", this.getPackageName());
     Button button = (Button) findViewById(resourceId);
     Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("level_1_img_" + i), null);
     button.setBackground(drawable);
```

when running on **Arabic** or **Persian** local  `i` changed to local number and throw exception. `images/level1/۹.png`

I want to prevent this change, how to do this?

Comment: i = 9 given from user side ?  or u type statically

Comment: its type statically in code

Comment: one more question r u change Arabic From Device setting Or Change by application Locale

Comment: no default local in device

Comment: give me that code how u can change locale

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147366/discussion-between-vishal-patel-and-mohammad-javad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per we discuss

Just change .

```
images.add(String.Formate("images/level1.....
```

To

```
images.add("images/level1/"+i+".png")
```